# EclipseLink can not insert an entity into oracle

Tags: caching, eclipselink, sequence

I built an entity with id using oracle sequence like that.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="C_ESTIMATE")
public class Estimate implements Serializable{

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     public Estimate(){}

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "estimatenoGen")
     @SequenceGenerator(name="estimatenoGen",sequenceName="AUTOSERIALNO",allocationSize=1)
     @Column(name="ESTIMATENO")
     private long id;
  }
```

When I call `em.persist(new Estimate())`,

EclipseLink prompts `Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraints` .

Sometimes it works correctly, sometimes failure, it is so strange. 
This entity was deployed several weblogic servers. 
Has EclipseLink bug on generating id using oracle sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be any issue on Oracle.

Can recreate the issue?  Enable logging, is a duplicate id being used?

How did you create your SEQUENCE object on the database?